# Best way to handle groups of items that can be manipulated either individually or in groups?

Tags: sql, data-modeling

Suppose there is an app that allows people to rent objects (holiday houses in my case), and it uses a relational databse.

Houses are unique and have an ID (unlike identical hotel rooms for example).

However, it is possible to group certain objects together, and nearly everything that can be done with individual objects can also be done with the groups.

For example, users can create a booking for certain house, or for a certain house group. It must be possible to quickly find out which bookings affect a certain house, regardless of whether that booking was for the individual house or the house group.

In a previous attempt to model this, I had a table of "houses" and "house groups". Similarly, I had "bookings" and "group bookings", and "pricing" and "group pricing", with seemingly near duplicate-sections of group and non-group sections in my code. There was a lot of repetition and it was hard to maintain.

How would you go about modeling this to avoid repetition?

Comment: Loose the groups tables altogether. Have a bookings table and bookings details table. in the bookings table keep only booking related data such as start date, end date, price etc'. In the booking details table keep the houses ids that where booked.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, going to do that!